# find common rows between two dataframes based on two columns using bash

Tags: unix, awk

I found this very difficult to solve in bash - I have two files that I want to find the common rows between them based on two columns.

f1.csv:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
Dalir,Cpne1,down,2174
Fendrr,Aco2,up,280
Cpne1,Tox1,down,8900
```

f2.csv

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
Linc,Rmo,ch2,ch2,p,l
Tox1,Cpne1,ch1,ch2,l,p
```

so basically the code should look only at the first two columns of the dfs and see if pairs are the same (the order of the pairs is not important). So you can see that in the first df there is
`Cpne1,Tox1` in the third row and in the second df there is `Tox1,Cpne1` in the second row - so this should be printed in the output from the second file.

Desired output:

```
Tox1,Cpne1
```

Unfortunately, I have not been able to develop a bash command for this - it would be great if you could help me with this. Thanks

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{pair[$1,$2];next} ($1,$2) in pair||($2,$1) in pair{print $1,$2}' f1.csv f2.csv`, or something like that

Comment: Thank you Ozgun - could you please describe each section of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the explanation to oguz' fine answer in the comments above:

`BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}`   defines `,` to be the separator for both input and output.

`NR==FNR{pair[$1,$2];next}` while the record number of the entire input matches the current file's record number (in other words, for the first file) add an element with the first and second field as index to the array `pair`.

`($1,$2) in pair||($2,$1) in pair{print $1,$2}`  operating on the second file, check if field one and two in any order are present as index in the array `pair`, and print them if they are.